# JVM Max heap size

Tags: mac-osx, java, jmx

For an application I use JVM Max heap setting when starting it on both a test environment and a production system. When i connect via JMX to monitor the application I see that the max heap size of production app is not the same as test application. I use -Xmx2000m on both and on test environment I get 1,864,171,520 B and on production I get 2,009,726,976 B.

So my questions are
-Is this info reliable. The Java versions and the machines are identical (Mac OS X 10.5).

-If this info is reliable then what could be causing this and how can it be changed so both systems behave the same for max heap size setting.

Comment: Is the architecture identical?

Comment: Is the the same JVM engine/version on both servers?

Comment: Does the application work with data? Is the data the same at both machines?

Comment: architechture and jvm are same. The data is not the same. And data in production does cause the application to be killed so it was restarted. Then I noticed that Max heap size for a fresh start application is less than the one which has been running for a while. Atleast this is what JMX tells me. I am still not sure why that is the case, may be I have to look into how heap size is managed by JVM over a lifetime of an application.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM will not automatically allocated the **-Xmx** amount of memory, so very minor environmental differences could cause the two virtual machines to end up with different process sizes (and for 2 GB, 139 MB is and arguably small difference, no ?)

See this post on [JVM Memory Usage](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/aiqa/archive/2005/04/jvm_memory_usag.html).